# Rapsberry Pi 2 does not read GPIO input

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2, gpio

I have a very short code like this, it detects the GPIO input and prints the string if the button is pressed. However it won't work. Any helps?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
while True:
    if GPIO.input(13):
        print("pressed")
```

Comment: What do you have the input connected to, and now?

Comment: I attached my switch on pin 13 and 14

Answer (score 0):

You have configured this GPIO incorrectly for the way the switch is connected. The pin is pulled low while idle, and is active low when the switch is closed; there is no way to distinguish between the two!

You will need to either connect the switch to a 3V3 pin (i.e, pins 1 or 17), or set the pin to pull up (`GPIO.PUD_UP`) while the switch is open.